# Stylesheet required elements

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am tasked with converting all of our Excel Interop to OpenXML, and I am currently learning about its formatting.  I was following [this example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisquon/archive/2009/11/30/stylizing-your-excel-worksheets-with-open-xml-2-0.aspx) which I have clipped down to the following code:

```
private Stylesheet GenerateStyleSheet() {
    // see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisquon/archive/2009/11/30/stylizing-your-excel-worksheets-with-open-xml-2-0.aspx for example

    return new Stylesheet(
    new Fonts(
    new Font( // Index 0 - The default font.
    new FontSize() {
        Val = 13
    },
    new Color() {
        Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() {
            Value = "000000"
        }
    },
    new FontName() {
        Val = "Calibri"
    }),
    new Font( // Index 1 - The bold font.
    new Bold(),
    new FontSize() {
        Val = 13
    },
    new Color() {
        Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() {
            Value = "000000"
        }
    },
    new FontName() {
        Val = "Calibri"
    })),
    new Fills(
    new Fill( // Index 0 - The default fill.
    new PatternFill() {
        PatternType = PatternValues.None
    }),
    new Fill( // Index 1 - The default fill of gray 125 (required)
    new PatternFill() {
        PatternType = PatternValues.Gray125
    }),
    new Fill( // Index 2 - The yellow fill.
    new PatternFill(
    new ForegroundColor() {
        Rgb = new HexBinaryValue() {
            Value = "FFFFFF00"
        }
    }) {
        PatternType = PatternValues.Solid
    })),
    new Borders(
    new Border( // Index 0 - The default border.
    new LeftBorder(),
    new RightBorder(),
    new TopBorder(),
    new BottomBorder(),
    new DiagonalBorder())),
    new CellFormats(
    new CellFormat() {
        FontId = 0,
    }, // Index 0 - The default cell style.  If a cell does not have a style index applied it will use this style combination instead
    new CellFormat() {
        FontId = 1, ApplyFont = true
    } // Index 1 - Bold 
    )); // return
}
```

Notice that no cell format references any border yet in my example, so I don't need the borders element.  However, if I comment that out, the generated Excel file produces an error when opening.

Is this element required in the stylesheet?

If I instead replace the borders part with `new Borders(new Border())` it seems to work fine.  Just wondering if anyone knew this without me having to read through the entire ECMA specs.

UPDATE:  At the least, anyone have a way of getting more verbose error output from Excel than *Repaired Records:  Format from /xl/styles.xml part (Styles)* ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find list of all available elements on [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.stylesheet_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx). For second part of your question: you can use OpenXMLTool that ships with 2.5 version to do validation of your output and it will tell you what's wrong with file structure.